# GWT DateBoxPopUp is not displayed properly

Tags: gwt

We have a gwt date box in our project where date picker(dateboxpopup) gets misplaced when we click on date box in chrome 61 version. It is working fine in chrome version less than 61 and in other browsers.[Date picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6imv.png)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [specific bug](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9542) has been fixed in GWT 2.8.2.

Comment: We are using <gwt.version>2.3.0</gwt.version> and we are still seeing the issue which is there in above image

Comment: See https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9542#issuecomment-335417356 for details on how to "backport" the fix. Though honestly, it's high time to update your project! GWT 2.3.0 was released 6.5 years ago, at the time Chrome was version 11 !

Comment: I am seeing this error when i am trying to update the gwt versiont o 2.8.2     
 --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.2:compile (default) @ mxEnablement ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [mxEnablement, mxEnablementTool]
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.google.gwt.dev.javac.BytecodeSignatureMaker$CompileDependencyVisitor has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)